# How to count files in subdir and filter output in bash

Tags: bash

Hi hoping someone can help, I have some directories on disk and I want to count the number of files in them (as well as dir size if possible) and then strip info from the output. So far I have this

```
find . -type d -name "*,d" -print0 | xargs -0 -I {} sh -c 'echo -e $(find "{}" | wc -l) "{}"' | sort -n
```

This gets me all the dir's that match my pattern as well as the number of files - great!

This gives me something like

```
2 ./bob/sourceimages/psd/dzv_body.psd,d
2 ./bob/sourceimages/psd/dzv_body_nrm.psd,d
2 ./bob/sourceimages/psd/dzv_body_prm.psd,d
2 ./bob/sourceimages/psd/dzv_eyeball.psd,d
2 ./bob/sourceimages/psd/t_zbody.psd,d
2 ./bob/sourceimages/psd/t_gear.psd,d
2 ./bob/sourceimages/psd/t_pupil.psd,d
2 ./bob/sourceimages/z_vehicles_diff.tga,d
2 ./bob/sourceimages/zvehiclesa_diff.tga,d
5 ./bob/sourceimages/zvehicleswheel_diff.jpg,d
```

From that I would like to filter based on max number of files so > 4 for example, I would like to capture filetype as a variable for each remaining result e.g ./bob/sourceimages/zvehicleswheel_diff.**jpg**,d

I guess I could use awk for this? 
Then finally I would like like to remove all the results from disk, with find I normally just do something like -exec rm -rf {} \; but I'm not clear how it would work here

Thanks a lot

EDITED

While this is clearly not the answer, these commands get me the info I want in the form I want it. I just need a way to put it all together and not search multiple times as that's total rubbish

```
filetype=$(find . -type d -name "*,d" -print0 | awk 'BEGIN { FS = "." }; { 
print $3 }' | cut -d',' -f1)
filesize=$(find . -type d -name "*,d" -print0 | xargs -0 -I {} sh -c 'du -h 
{};' | awk '{ print $1 }')
filenumbers=$(find . -type d -name "*,d" -print0 | xargs -0 -I {} sh -c 
'echo -e $(find "{}" | wc -l);')
```

Comment: what does mean *filetype **as a variable***?

Comment: Sorry, to clarify, I want the bold part in my question stored somewhere to echo for example. If I was doing this in powershell, I'd create an array of strings and use something like    $a.split('.')[2].split(',')[0] to turn ./bob/sourceimages/zvehicleswheel_diff.jpg,d into just jpg

Answer (score 0):

```
files_count=`ls -keys | nl`
```

For instance:

```
ls | nl
```

nl printed numbers of lines

Comment: [Don't parse ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) !! As is, your solution adds 1 to the expected result (because `ls -l` adds a line `total XXX` to its output)